# Create multibranch pipeline via groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ansible

I'd like to create new Multibranch pipeline in Jenkins via groovy script. Is it possible ?
Until now, I am using kind of workaround where I created Multibranch pipeline manualy, saved config.xml and later on I am just importing this file. 
It should be part of Ansible configuration, therefore I would prefer to have groovy script instead of importing xml.
Thanks

Comment: I assume that your pipeline is already stored in a `Jenkinsfile` and not directly in the XML. Otherwise read the documentation.

Comment: This question makes sense to me and it surprises me that there is such a mess of options for configuring Jenkins, none of which are fully featured.

Comment: The Groovy/Java APIs work fine, but the documentation and examples are rather lacking. I've taken to reading the Java test cases for clues here.

Comment: This might help 
https://github.com/williamroberts/jenkins/blob/6979d7da5c3839e07a6ffa0cdfbfd4f6f33eb12b/groovy-scripts/script_5_create_organisation_folder.groovy

Answer (score 1):

The way to go here is the [Job DSL](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl). With that, you can define a [`multibranchPipelineJob`](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/multibranchPipelineJob).

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I guess that I have to create "seed job" manually anyway if I'd like to use Job DSL plugin.

Comment: Use the config management tooling of your choice to create that (chef, ansible, docker etc). Nice example: [tknerr/jenkins-pipes-*](https://github.com/tknerr/jenkins-pipes-infra).

Comment: I assume you have multiple MultiBranch jobs so that it's worth bundling them in one seed job.

Comment: This approach doesn't let you set alternative pipeline scripts in the same repo. The DSL syntax is quite limited compared to the other job types ... which might be why the original question was asking about doing it with Groovy ... it's certainly what lead me here.

Comment: Well.. it's possible: `configure { it / factory(class: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowBranchProjectFactory'){ scriptPath('.jenkins/build.Jenkinsfile') ..`